# Getting a strange words array as Hash , why?

Tags: node.js, hash

```
const sha256 = require('crypto-js/sha256');

console.log(sha256("what the hell??"));
```

I am getting:

```
{ words:
   [ 406305836,
     1416447687,
     86002937,
     -128468725,
     499121450,
     2038973718,
     1880201541,
     -1170628341 ],
  sigBytes: 32 }
```

Why is that??

It was working fine and getting a normal hash on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I should add .toString()

such `as console.log(sha256("what the hell??").toString());`